# decomposition induced by a conditional expectation on $C^*$-algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $B$ be a $C^*$-subalgebra of a $C^*$-algebra $A$ and suppose that  $\theta: A\rightarrow B$ is a conditional expectation. Does there exist a $C^*$-subalgebra $C$ of $A$ such that

$A=B\oplus C$ ?

Can we take $C=\ker \theta$?

Answer (score 1):

In general, $A$ is not $\ast$-isomorphic to $B\oplus C$ for a $C^\ast$-algebra $C$. Take for example $A=M_2(\mathbb C)$, $B=\mathbb C 1$, and $\theta\colon A\to B,\,a\mapsto \frac 1 2\mathrm{tr}(a)1$ (or any conditional expectation induced by a state). If $A\cong B\oplus C$, then $C$ must be 3-dimensional. But the only 3-dimensional $C^\ast$-algebra is $\mathbb C^3$, and $M_2(\mathbb C)\not\cong \mathbb C\oplus\mathbb C^3=\mathbb C^4$ since the left side is noncommutative, while the right side is commutative.

In fact, since it has trivial center, $M_n(\mathbb C)$ cannot be written as direct sum of any non-zero $C^\ast$-algebras $B,C$.

Comment: But I saw a similar conlusion in Porta amd Recht's paper "conditional and expectations and opertaor decompositions". For a C*-algbera $A$ with a conditional expectation $\Phi:A\rightarrow A$ onto a subalgebra $B$, we have the decomposition $A=B\oplus H$, where $H=\ker \Phi$.

Comment: @mathbeginner You suppressed the crucial word "linear" here. They claim that there is a "linear decomposition" $A=B\oplus H$, i.e., it's a direct sum of Banach spaces with no claim regarding the algebra structure.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we take $C=\ker\theta$?

Only if $A=B\oplus C$. In general, that's not the case; $\ker\theta$ is not even a subalgebra in general. For instance take $A=M_2(\mathbb C)$, $B$ the diagonal matrices, and
$$
\theta:\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\ c&d\end{bmatrix}\longmapsto\begin{bmatrix} a&0\\0&d\end{bmatrix}. 
$$

Comment: If the above conclusion des not hold, I don't understand why the following result is correct : Suppse $E_D:L(H_d)\rightarrow D$ is the conditional expection ono $D$ and $Z_d\in L(H_d)$, then we have $W_e(E_D(Z_{H_d}))\subset W_e(Z_{H_d})$, where $W_e()$ is the essential numerical range of an opertaor.